# Can't "wget" from my home Debian Lenny server! But the ports are opened!

Tags: linux, debian, dns, wget

I have a very strange problem for me.
In this example dns and IP is hiden for security reason.
When I try from putty manager to connect to my Debian and write next command:

```
    debian:~# wget http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/archive.tar
--2011-04-03 03:35:27--  http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/archive.tar
Resolving myhost.no-ip.org... xx.10x.66.xxx
Connecting to myhost.no-ip.org|xx.10x.66.xxx|:1082... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2011-04-03 03:38:42--  (try: 2)  http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/cccam.tar
Connecting to myhost.no-ip.org|xx.10x.66.xxx|:1082... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2011-04-03 03:41:53--  (try: 3)  http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/cccam.tar
Connecting to myhost.no-ip.org|xx.10x.66.xxx|:1082... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

..I can't connect to my Debian server! This message stay till I press ctrl+z.

But when I try to wget any other site it working!
Very strange thing is when I type:

```
http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/archive.tar
```

command in my firefox web browser the file is reachable and download is strated.
So, my port is open. Am I right?
What can be the problem?
Here is my config from networking :

```
debian:~# cat /etc/networking/interfaces
cat: /etc/networking/interfaces: No such file or directory
debian:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
### The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

###The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.50.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.50.255
gateway 192.168.50.99
debian:~#
```

The archive.tar file is putted to /vat/www/archive.tar
Local port 80 is forwared in my router to external port 1082
My no.ip dns address is vaild and reachable through firefox.
Have someone any suggestion what coud be a problem?
Thx.

..I can't connect to my Debian server! This message stay till I press ctrl+z.

But when I try to wget any other site it working!
Very strange thing is when I type:

```
http://myhost.no-ip.org:1082/archive.tar
```

command in my firefox web browser the file is reachable and download is strated.
So, my port is open. Am I right?
What can be the problem?
Here is my config from networking :

```
debian:~# cat /etc/networking/interfaces
cat: /etc/networking/interfaces: No such file or directory
debian:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
### The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

###The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.50.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.50.255
gateway 192.168.50.99
debian:~#
```

The archive.tar file is putted to /vat/www/archive.tar
Local port 80 is forwared in my router to external port 1082
My no.ip dns address is vaild and reachable through firefox.
Have someone any suggestion what coud be a problem?
Thx.

Comment: So your Debian machine is outside of your home network? It's not really clear how your network looks, what is where. Have you tried to wget the file from port 80? Does that work? You should really clarify how the network looks. What machine is in what "physical" location (no we don't need the town, number the locations or whatever) and what service is accessed from where and fails.

Comment: If you read my network config I think you could concluded that is in my home network.
I'm tryed connect to debian from other windows pc from my second ISP (not from IP where is debian) through putty.
My port is forwarded as I said, I know it is open because I can reach it through web (firefox). On this port I have a web page that is reachable in firefox.
Yes I tried to forward to port 80.
All machines is physical in physical locations at my home.

Comment: Can anyone help???

Answer (score 0):

The issue *might* be that your routing tables, or your ASDL router's, are being too clever, and a LAN-connection attempt to the external address is being re-written or routed to the machine internally.  That is, your packets are not visiting the WAN.

That is an issue, because you are only listening on :1082 on your WAN, not your LAN.

Try adjusting your apache so that it listens on 1082.  If the connection *is* being routed internal to the LAN, the connection is arriving to your server on port 1082.